# Change order header apache

Tags: php, apache, web-config, http-headers

how to change order header the following line

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>
> Date: Sat, 24 Aug 2013 05:10:06 GMT
>
> Content-Length: 0
>
> Server: apache
>
> Pragma: no-cache
>
> X-Powered-By: PHP5

to :

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>
> Pragma: no-cache
>
> Content-Length: 0
>
> Server: apache
>
> X-Powered-By: PHP5
>
> Date: Sat, 24 Aug 2013 05:10:06 GMT

in apache

Comment: why would you change the order? is there any reason for that ?

Comment: I want to change line 2 to line 6

Comment: I want to change date position in response